# Android studio java: HashMap with one single string and one array

Tags: java, android, arrays, hashmap

I'm working on a project that works with an online API.
Everything up to this point is working great.
One API call to add items to an invoice is making me beat my head in the door.

This is the array I need to send:

`{id = 84, new_item={price=69.99, title=new item}}`

I got my invoice items array no problem:

```
    `JSONObject items = new JSONObject();
    JSONObject it = new JSONObject();
    try {
        items.put("id",id);
        it.put("title",item);
        it.put("price",price);
        items.put("new_item",it);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }`
```

This now gives me:

`{"id":"84","new_item":{"title":"ffffvvv","price":"6.99"}}`

But my function is still expecting a hashmap.  I'm thinking it would be worth it to change the previous calls to that function and have it expect a JsonObject?  I have not got so far that that will take much more than an hour.

Comment: Hi there, and welcome to Stack Overflow. I will attempt to answer your question below, but it would be clearer and easier to answer for me and others if you could include the code you used to "try to add the id" along with the stack trace (error message) it produced when it did not work :)

Comment: Also, what are you using to serialize your HashMap?

Comment: why don't you create a class for your data, then probably all you will needs is a `HashMap<String, MyClass>`

Comment: I kinda like your idea Wombat.  I noticed some examples about that in my search.  I will look into that option tomorrow and let you all know how that goes.

Comment: Part of the issue may be simply understanding the problem. You keep referring to “array”, yet you have no arrays here - you have maps, and maps of maps. In fact it looks exactly like a JSON object.  Is your input supposed to be an array? Assuming the format is correct, just use any json library to generate it, not HashMap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is in my edit of the main post.  I was trying to use HashMap to build an object of parameters to send to an API.
That worked fine until I needed to mix it up and put an object in an object but with some simple string values as well.  Java just don't like that.
The HashMap idea was simply replaced with a JsonObject instead.
I should have done this from the beginning but I am just a beginner.
Since Invoice and Client views are the only ones I've done.  It only took about 30 minutes to replace all the existing function calls.  BAM!!  Done.
Hope this helps someone.  When you really think you have found the solution.  Don't be afraid to look a bit further.  Make sure it's the right solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think I see your problem, please let me know if I've misunderstood. You have an object `myArray` of type `HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>>`. This means it is a map which *maps* strings to maps, those maps in turn map Strings to other Strings

Naturally, your first `myArray.put()` works because you are `put`-ing an object (`value`) of type `HashMap<String, String>` into `myArray`, labeling it `"new_item"`. In your map, you have `"new_item" -> value`.

Then, you'd like to put a new thing into `myArray`, this thing being `"id" -> 84`. `"id"` is a String, so it is a correct type of key to put into `myArray`, but the **value** has to be of type `HashMap<String, String>`. `84` is an `int`, even `"84"` wouldn't work, because it's a `String`, not a `HashMap<String, String>`

If you want your map, `myArray`, to contain both `"new_item" -> value` **and** `"id" -> 84` then `value` and `84` must be of the same type. The easiest thing to do is *probably* to change `myArray` to be a `HashMap<String, String>` and convert `value` and `84` to `String` before placing them in `myArray`. This is true if what you do after is use `myArray` as a `String` (to send a request, print, etc.).

Comment: I've tried that and I got no errors, the API returned success but the item was not added to the invoice.  Was thinking that the API wants the new_item to be an array.  Does that make sense?

Comment: I've done this with PHP but I'm a complete tard when it comes to Java.

Comment: It's hard to respond without more detail. Could you include 1.) **all** the relevant original code (namely: adding to the invoice, and any other steps between the code above and that) and 2.) the exact code you ran when you tried what I wrote above?

Comment: I love the responses.  Thank you.  Unfortunately today I have a list of other peoples broken toys to fix.  AKA, a busy day.  Hopefully this evening I will post more.  Also though, I have thought about the json object idea Krease.  Sorry to keep you guys waiting, It's getting cold here and my mother's furnace broke.  I will get back to this.  Thanks everyone.

Comment: Okay.  So this is what I did based on Krease's idea with a json object.

Comment: Krease !!!!!!!  Your the man!!  I think, otherwise, your the Woman...  What ever.  Thanks, problem solved, should have gone this route from the get go.  JsonObject it is, HashMap was the wrong idea for the job.

Comment: Glad to help. For future reference, you can tag ppl in comments with @ so they get notified. Nice to see this as an answer too, hopefully it will help more people.